# AND OR syntax inside strtotime/array

Tags: php, arrays, strtotime

i develop a program that you cannot see the data if it is older or younger than 1 days, so you can only see the TODAY data, TOMORROW data, and YESTERDAY data.

i tried using or/and syntax inside my array and strtotime but it's not working.

I tried this:

```
   $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 days"));

    $query = $this->db->get_where('info',array(dates => $date2 or $date or $date1)

);
```

I also tried this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 days"));
$datefix = $date or $date1 or $date2;

$query = $this->db->get_where('info',array(dates => $datefix));
```

both doesnot work. I searching for how to use OR and AND syntax inside ARRAY or STRTOTIME and i couldnot find it. Can anyone help me with this? Little help would be appreciated!

Comment: What database class are you using?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i used MySQL for the database and CodeIgniter for the framework. This is my model to show data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$this->db->where('dates <=', $date1);
$this->db->where('dates >=', $date2);
$query = $this->db->get('info');
```

**OR**

```
$this->db->where('dates', $date);
$this->db->where('dates', $date1);
$this->db->where('dates', $date2);
$query = $this->db->get('info');
```

Comment: Just tried this, also does not work. It works if there is only one condition thou. Am i wrong in the "date" part ?

Comment: What is the generated SQL? You can get that if your database class has something that will display the generated SQL statement to check

Comment: can i see your table structure @MikaelLouis

Comment: Actually this is working! I tried the first one, but i reverse the <= date1 into >= date1 and >= into <= date2. Thanks! @shubham715

Comment: glad to help u :) @MikaelLouis

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to check the syntax of the query. because it's totally wrong. Use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT *
FROM `TABLENAME`
WHERE (dates BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')
```

I hope it helps!!!!